# Can a function return an object? Objective-C and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, oop, class, function, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray. It's members eventually become members of an array instance in a class. I want to put the instantiantion of NSMutable into a function and to return an array object. If I can do this, I can make some of my code easier to read. Is this possible?

Here is what I am trying to figure out.

```
//Definition:
function Objects (float a, float b) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:a]];
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:b]];  
    //[release array]; ????????
    return array;
}

//Declaration:
 Math *operator = [[Math alloc] init];
    [operator findSum:Objects(20.0,30.0)];
```

My code compiles if I instantiate NSMutableArray right before I send the message to the receiver. I know I can have an array argument along with the method. What I have problem seeing is how to use a function and to replace the argument with a function call. Any help is appreciated. I am interested in the concept not in suggestions to replace the findSum method.

Comment: @seaworthy: This is not a valid C function declaration at all. To declare a function in C, you simply provide the return type (in this case NSMutableArray*), then the function name, followed by the list of formal parameters. There are other qualifier keywords, but that is the basic. C has no notion of a "function" keyword to declare functions. This should not even compile.

Comment: actually, this wasn't ever part of my code, it is an abstract representation. I was trying to figure out a way that squeegy showed and did not realize that you can define a function as an Obj-C type. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: If you are using ARC (Automatic reference counting) then autorelease is no longer possible.
You may have to add some indicator that the result should be autoreleased.
Not sure how that should be done though.

Comment: it does the right thing by default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use autorelease to return objects you create in methods/functions.

```
NSMutableArray* Objects(float a, float b) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
                     // or: [NSMutableArray array];

    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:a]];
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:b]];  
    return array;
}
```

Or simply:

```
NSMutableArray* Objects(float a, float b) {
    return [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:a],
             [NSNumber numberWithFloat:b],
             nil];
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid C function declaration. Also, you need to specify your return type.

Comment: Note: `[NSMutableArray array]` is shorthand for `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`.

Comment: @mipadi: not sure, what you mean. It doesn't work.
@squeegy: thanks!

Comment: @ squeegy: Does the first example add nil? or I need to add 

[array addObject:nil];

Comment: In the second example, it's providing a nil terminated list.  The `nil` tells the method that there are no more objects to add.  The final array has 2 objects in it.  The first example doesn't use a `nil` because you are adding each object one at a time.  In both examples, you end up with an array with 2 objects in it.  In fact, you cannot add nil to an `NSArray` at all.